# How to restore .config from backup?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I'm reinstalling Ubuntu after numerous problems.  I backed up using Deja Dup.  Restoring files went fine except for a backup called .config which says:

```
Could not restore following files.  Please make sure you are able to write to them.

/home/paul/.config/opera/SingletonCookie
/home/paul/.config/opera/SingletonLock
/home/paul/.config/opera/SingletonSocket
/home/paul/.config/pulse/8e0a66cdc36b4006aa83b2b80c55223d-runtime
/home/paul/.config/xfce4/desktop/icons.screen.latest.rc
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: exist this directory `/home/paul/.config/opera`? @PaulM

Comment: Yes.  The .config file must be hidden because it doesn't show up in the window but if I type in the address I can get to it and the path to opera exists.  Maybe there are admin privileges I need in order to restore these files?

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  Being able to access the .config directory by typing in the path (the folder is hidden but still accessible)  I was able to find the files listed above.  I moved those files to trash and did a restore of ,config from my backup and everything is working fine now.
Thanks go to lucki1000 for helping me find the .config directory.